# Is it possible to connect a signal to a static slot without a receiver instance?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

Is it possible to connect a signal to static slot without receiver instance?

Like this: `connect(&object, SIGNAL(some()), STATIC_SLOT(staticFooMember()));`

There is a `QApplication::closeAllWindows()` function with [static slot] attribute in Qt documentation. And there is an example of using it from the documentation:

```
exitAct = new QAction(tr("E&xit"), this);
exitAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Quit);
exitAct->setStatusTip(tr("Exit the application"));
connect(exitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(closeAllWindows()));
```

Is it allowed to do the same action but without passing an instance variable (e.g. when a class has only static functions)?

```
class Some : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    static void foo();
private:
    Some();
};
```

---

Maybe Frank Osterfeld is right and it is better to use singleton pattern in this case but I am still surprised why this feature has not been implemented yet.

**Update:**

[In Qt 5 it is possible](http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update for QT5: Yes you can**

```
static void someFunction() {
    qDebug() << "pressed";
}
// ... somewhere else
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, someFunction);
```

**In QT4 you can't:**

No it is not allowed. Rather, it is allowed to use a slot which is a static function, but to be able to connect it you need an instance.

In their example,

```
connect(exitAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(closeAllWindows()));
```

means than they previously called

```
QApplication* qApp = QApplication::instance();
```

Edit:

The only interface for connecting object is the function

```
bool QObject::connect ( const QObject * sender, const QMetaMethod & signal, const QObject * receiver, const QMetaMethod & method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection )
```

How are you going to get rid of `const QObject * receiver`?

Check the `moc` files in your project, it speaks by itself.

Comment: Yes it is. I don't understand why is it impossible to invoke static function without object in Qt Meta-Object System?

Comment: I agree is it a drawback of the Qt system, still it is not possible.

Comment: Can't see much of a drawback. Static functions with side-effects are evil anyway, and one can use a singleton QObject instances if need be.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld My problem with it is, when coupled with the fact that you can't declare a QObject in a cpp file, it requires adding 2 files to your project just to subscribe to a signal.

Comment: @sashoalm: If you're using Qt 5 and C++11 features, you could now use signals with lambdas.

Comment: The function must not necessarily be static, see answer from ManuelSchneid3r

Answer (score 5):

[It is.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4) (With Qt5)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

void foo(){
    qDebug() << "focusChanged";
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QObject::connect(&app, &QApplication::focusChanged, foo);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of Qt, although you cannot do so as mentioned by @UmNyobe but you can do something like this if you really want to call that static slot :

```
connect(&object, SIGNAL(some()), this, SLOT(foo()));

void foo()
{
    .... //call your static function here.
}
```