# Qt 5.3 Signals and Slots, Simple Function and Lambda Expression

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, signals-slots, qt5.3

I tried to Write a program using Qt 5.3 and I try to using signals and slots as practice. I wrote the following code (part of the code) :

```
void exitToWin()
    {
        exit(0);
    }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    QMessageBox EndBox;
    QObject::connect((EndBox.button(QMessageBox::Ok)),SIGNAL(clicked()),exitToWin);
    w.show();
    EndBox.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I even change the declaration of the function to `static` and I checked the expression with parentheses and without them while I am writing the `connect` command. but although what Qt documented and what its IDE guided to. also I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153029/qt-designer-how-to-connect-a-signal-to-a-static-function)  and I tested it.
Moreover I tried with lambda expression as below:

```
QObject::connect((EndBox.button(QMessageBox::Ok)),SIGNAL(clicked()),[=](){
    exit(0);
});
```

but still I receive errors indicate "No matching function call".
And after all I have to say that I am using Microsoft Windows 7.

Comment: Did youu try to rewrite that wihout SIGNAL declaration like here: http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html ?

Comment: @Tanuki Yes! I read it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on Qt 5.3:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

void exitToWin()
{
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    QMessageBox endBox;
    endBox.addButton(QMessageBox::Ok); // (2)
    endBox.connect(endBox.button(QMessageBox::Ok), 
                   &QAbstractButton::clicked, exitToWin); // (1)
    /* This works, too:
    endBox.connect(endBox.button(QMessageBox::Ok),
                   &QAbstractButton::clicked,
                   [] () { exit(0); });
    */
    w.show();
    endBox.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's why:

`(1)` You can use `endBox`'s QObject to do the connection between the `QAbstractButton`'s `clicked` signal and your `exitToWin` simple function. You also can't connect a SIGNAL to a simple function or a lambda, so we use the member function variety, instead.

`(2)` endBox doesn't actually get an OK button by default. When you mention it on line `(1)` in your code, it creates it, but not in time (apparently) to pass the pointer back to `connect`, so we create it first here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested something else, as you mentioned in line 2 we can use `QPushButtom` too, it work, I think the problem relates to what you mentioned in line 2.

Comment: the Problem is still with lambda expression, can you help?

Comment: make sure you have the `-std=c++11` flag set.

Comment: I added in Built steps but the I received the unknown command error

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work for two reasons:

Firstly, `QMessageBox` does not have such a signal. See [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qmessagebox.html#signals) for the signals it does have.

Secondly, when making connections from a signal to a slot (or lambda function), you must define the function signatures, not specific values.

If a signal can pass a variety of values and you only want your slot to perform a certain function on a selection of those values (in this case, only if the value `QMessageBox::Ok` is passed) it is up to the slot to interrogate the values, not the `connect` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Since the *connect()* method is from *QObject* it has to be called from a *QObject* child containing the *Q_OBJECT* macro in its declaration. Running *qmake* prepare the class to send signals and receive slots.

Comment: `QObject::connect` is a static function.