# How to use static slot function in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I've this code snippet:

```
class Server{
public slot:
    static void readMessage();
};

// somewhere in the main code...
connect(tcpsocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, Server::readMessage);
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(const
>   Object*&, void (QIODevice::*&)(), const Object*&, void (Server::*&)(),
>   Qt::ConnectionType)'
>            return connect(sender, signal, sender, slot, Qt::DirectConnection);

I don't know how to deal with that.

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428213/6165833

Comment: You can do this in Qt5 only. Which version of Qt do you use?

Comment: I use _Qt_5_9_1_

Comment: Why you need "static" modifier here?

Comment: This syntax works: QObject::connect(tcpsocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, &Server::readMessage);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
connect( tcpsocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, [](){ Server::readMessage(); });
```

Note: This will need C++11 compiler features.

Comment: It is NOT necessary to use lamndas, you can do it directly: `QObject::connect(tcpsocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, &Server::readMessage); `

Comment: @eyllanesc: Indeed, I was just giving another way to write it.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I Agree.