# Not able to connect signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt5

I wrote a basic C++ program for simulating the signal and slot process. I made a push button "`button`", a `QVBoxLayout` "`layout`". I added the button in the layout. Everything is fine till now. But when push button is made to connect by signal and slot, there's are two problem/errors.

1. "no instance of overloaded function "QObject::connect matches the argument list"."
2. 'QObject::connect': none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types.

Question:
I am sure that there's something missing, which I am not able to decipher. Here, the push button "`button`" has to invoke the function "`connectFunc`". Instead it gives me above two errors. How to make the button invoke the function?

This is my code.

```
#include "signalsslots.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include<qpushbutton.h>
#include<qboxlayout.h>
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void connectFunc()
{
    cout << endl << "connected " << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Press Here");
    QAction* bAction = new QAction;
    button->addAction(bAction);
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(button);
    
    
    //layout->SetFixedSize(200, 150);
    QObject::connect(bAction, SIGNAL(QPushButton::clicked()), &a,(connectFunc()));
    

    QWidget w;
    w.setLayout(layout);
    w.setWindowTitle("Signal and Slot Example !!!");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

FYI, I am using VS 2019 for writing Qt widget applications.

Comment: For one, you're missing the 'SLOT' macro. For another, why not use the Methodpointer notation? `QObject::connect(bAction, &QPushButton::clicked, &a, &connectFunc)`.
Does that work?

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response. You gave me two methods.
1. Using "SLOT" macro. 
`QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &a,SLOT(::connectFunc()));`
For this, it gave me a description in the console as "QObject::connect: No such slot QApplication::::connectFunc() in C:\Users\gkaly\source\repos\Qt\QtConcepts\SignalsSlots\main.cpp:24"



2. Using MethodPointer notation. It gave me same error in addition to the errors shown in main post.
   a. expressoin must be an Ivalue or a function designator
   b. '&' requires I-value.

Answer (score 1):

The `QObject::connect()` function that you use, connects a signal (i.e. a method) of an object to a slot (i.e. a method) of another object.

What you are telling QT is to connect the clicked() method of your QAction object, to the connectFunc() of your QApplication object. Both methods do not exist on those objects!

What you probably want is to connect the clicked() method of your QButton `button` to the free function connectFunc(). Like this:

```
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, &connectFunc);
```

Note that this requires QT5. (See [Is it possible to connect a signal to a static slot without a receiver instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428038/is-it-possible-to-connect-a-signal-to-a-static-slot-without-a-receiver-instance))